# Qt5 C++ - How to split color image efficiently into 3 channels without using OpenCV

Tags: image, colors, rgb

I have successfully extract the 3 channels from a color image by looping each of the pixel. However, this is way too slow and would like to ask for other more efficient and faster way to do it?

Below are my inefficient way of doing it:

```
for (int y = 0; y < HEIGHT; ++y)
{
    int x_stride = y * WIDTH;
    for (int x = 0; x < WIDTH; ++x)
    {
        int index = x_stride + x;
        QRgb rgb_1 = snap_buf_1.pixel(x, y);

        img_bit_red = qRed(rgb_1);
        img_bit_green = qGreen(rgb_1);
        img_bit_blue = qBlue(rgb_1);

        ucSnapBuffer1[0].GetBuffer_UNSAFE().data()[index] = img_bit_red;
        ucSnapBuffer1[1].GetBuffer_UNSAFE().data()[index] = img_bit_green;
        ucSnapBuffer1[2].GetBuffer_UNSAFE().data()[index] = img_bit_blue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to write it in C. Not because of C language, but so that you are not using so many functions: do you see the last 3 lines? 2 index indirection, two call of function. Get the buffer pointers once [per channel] (outside loop) and use them. Also `qRed` and similar: what they are doing? If you want to do efficiently, you must know what are you doing (so just one initial decision of calculation, and then you repeat always the same calculation. No need to check think at every pixels (and 3 times). Efficient means also transparent (at cost of flexibility).

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi. Thanks. Basically QRed() is the build in function from QT. Let me try to write it in traditional way rather than calling it.

Comment: Yeah, and probably it can handle different size (8 bits, 10 bits, etc.). But this is the problem: it will check and handle the correct case at every pixel. If you want to optimize, you must check at beginning, and then handle for the correct number of bit (probably you can optimize just 8 bit). In general, first step of micro-optimisation is to try to move things outside loops.